# Storage Clause is getting skipped for LOB segment in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, clob

Hi have created table which consist clob datatype :

```
CREATE TABLE MQ_GET_CLOB
(
  SEQ_NO          NUMBER                        NOT NULL,
  MESSAGE_TEXT    CLOB,
  MESSAGE_LENGTH  NUMBER                        NOT NULL,
  STATUS          VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
)
TABLESPACE DATA_L1
    LOB (MESSAGE_TEXT) STORE AS 
      (TABLESPACE DATA_L1
       STORAGE (INITIAL 6144)
       CHUNK 4000
       NOCACHE LOGGING);
```

After creating table when I looked into Metadata , I found that LOB storage clause is getting skipped.

```
CREATE TABLE MQ_GET_CLOB
(
  SEQ_NO          NUMBER                        NOT NULL,
  MESSAGE_TEXT    CLOB,
  MESSAGE_LENGTH  NUMBER                        NOT NULL,
  STATUS          VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
)
TABLESPACE DATA_L1
PCTUSED    40
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
```

Which leads to

> ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace
>   SYSAUX

I am not sure why table is using SYSAUX tablespace.
Whether anyone have faced same issue before ? This there something I have missed ?

Thanks.

Comment: How you came to know that skipped LOB clause lead to `ORA-01658` error?

Comment: As table metadata does not reflect about LOB storage after table creation..so it is using default user specific tablespace which is sysaux

Comment: How you extract the meta data of the table? I can see the LOB storage parameter in the DDL extracted using `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`. How you got the error? During the insert statement against this table?

Comment: I have extracted metadata using toad. We have recently migrated to 12c. I can see all old table which was create in 11g with clob columns have LOB storage clause. But newly created tables after upgrade seems missing it.

Comment: @NagendraNigade  No necessarily an answer to you question, but why have you set the user's default tablespace to SYSAUX?